# How can I disable nginx from Gitlab bunlde?

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, nginx, gitlab

- I've installed a Debian/Jessie server with an apache 2.4 service
- I downloaded and installed the bundle package of Gitlab for Debian 8
  (Jessie)
- I activate unicorn and configure a virtualhost in apache to work with
  a specific subdomain.

Now if I restart my server the bundled nginx will start before apache and listen on 80 port before.

I changed nginx config to listen on port 666 but the solution isn't really clean. Is there any way to simply disable this service from the bundle ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

after a short upgrade (gitlab-ctl upgrade) of gitlab, I can now see more configurations possible for nginx.

So from /etc/gitlab/gitlabrc there is a line:

```
#nginx['enable'] = true
```

Commented by default, if nginx continue to start you can uncomment it and change it to false like this.

```
nginx['enable'] = false
```

And restart the service with

```
gitlab-ctl restart
```

Comment: Note that the latest gitlab comes with an /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file, which needs an `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` after editing it.

Answer (score 0):

I once had it using Apache. There's a guide out there somewhere to do this. You'll need the ruby gem 'passenger' installed, and also the apache module 'passenger' (apache-mod-passenger I think).